# How to get innerHTML that contain ng-template?

Tags: angular, innerhtml, ng-template

This is my app.component.html:

```
<div #content>
    Hello world
    <ng-template>
        inside template
    </ng-template>
</div>
```

And this is my app.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('content', { read: ElementRef }) refContent: ElementRef;

...

console.log(this.refContent.nativeElement);
```

And this is the output:

```
<div _ngcontent-kst-c255=""> 
    Hello world 
    <!--container-->
</div>
```

How to get the console to print like this?

```
<div _ngcontent-kst-c255=""> 
    Hello world 
    inside template
</div>
```

Comment: What lifecycle hook (if any) are you calling the log in?

Comment: innerHTML is for rendered content, ng-template is not supposed to be rendered before you its been put in an outlet. the <!---container is to help angular find the viewContainerRef location cause you can use ng-templates for dynamically insert components

Comment: @Phix you are right, is a lifecycle issue. I wrapped it with a timeout, and it works now.

Answer (score 0):

I put a timeout of 1000 ms before calling

```
console.log(this.refContent.nativeElement);
```

And it works now. The renderer just need some time to render it.

Answer (score 0):

**Use Angular life cycle hook**

**ngAfterViewInit** : A callback method that is invoked immediately after Angular has completed initialization of a component's view. It is invoked only once when the view is instantiated.

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
//here put the ViewChild elements Reference variables
console.log(this.refContent.nativeElement);
}
```

Comment: The code in the question is a simplified version. My use case is to get the innerHTML after some server callback, and after render the UI. So a quick hack is to use a timeout to give time for the UI to complete render.